# Flutter error: "a value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'String' in a const constructor"

Tags: flutter

Older variations on this question seemed to hang on use of "const."

This one doesn't:

```
mixin MyCanvasPolicy implements CanvasPolicy, CustomStatePolicy {
  @override
  onCanvasTap() {
    multipleSelected = [];

    if (isReadyToConnect) {
      isReadyToConnect = false;
      canvasWriter.model.updateComponent(selectedComponentId);
    } else {
      selectedComponentId = null;
      hideAllHighlights();
    }
  }
}
```

I assume this is a problem of code not being updated.

This is the source:
[fdl_demo_app](https://github.com/Arokip/fdl_demo_app)

Comment: The code you show hasn't got anything to do with that error. Looks like it's a very old project without null-safety. It probably needs a lot of refactoring to make it runnable with more recent flutter version

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of...'

The example is exactly what I need, but has a lot of errors, which all seem to be related to null-safety, in one way or another.

Comment: It looks like the branch called `null-safety` on the same website made that refactoring. You can try use that one instead of `master`. It looks like that one should work fine

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be an issue with a string it's not accepting the NULL value
try to write string in such a way
String Your_String_Name = someValue ?? "";
it will assign an empty string if the value is NULL.